# [Django]Cant run collectstatic to upload media to S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I'm using the following configs to store static and media files to S3

```
USES_S3 = config('USES_S3') == 'True'

if USES_S3:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
    AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = config('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.{AWS_S3_REGION_NAME}.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=94608000'}
    STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
    MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
    STATICFILES_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/static/'
    MEDIAFILES_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/media/'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

However I keep getting the following error, when I try to run collectstatic

```
k_date = self._sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'),
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

It seems this error happens when you can't connect to S3. What am I doing wrong, any help appreciated.

Comment: What's the value of 'key' in this line? Is 'key' equal to None?

Comment: @NickODell I'm not sure, not sure how I can check either.

Comment: Have you configured `AWS_SECRET_KEY` somehow? I'd guess it's `None` at present.

Comment: @AKX How do I configure AWS secret key. Also I have a separate key for eb which works, guess the key for S3 isn't working.

Comment: I don't know what your `config()` function is; I'd _guess_ it's getting environment variables, but it's hard to tell. Either way, you'd set it the same way you've set `USES_S3` to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today.

settings.py was looking fine, but the app still didn't connect to S3 and returned None instead of secret key.

From the info I found in similar themes there is some mismatch in list of regions django-storage can use and regions available in AWS.
I was using eu-central-1 (Frankfurt) and repeatedly getting same NoneType error no matter what settings/permissions I made from both the app and AWS. So, I just decided to create new bucket in us-west-2 (Oregon). And miracle - it works. Write and read static files. Then I swapped back to eu-central-1 bucket to double check (with same settings as for us-west-2) and... get NoneType error again.

Conclusion: something wrong with django-storage + some AWS regions.

Try to swap to another region from what you are using right now.